# Paw ask me to login but show error accessing MacOS Key Chain

Tags: paw-app

I have a valid Paw license that I migrated few month ago but today is requesting me to Migrate license or login. When I log in I get this error after clicking in the `Link with Paw` button, any hint?:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this bug was affecting users for which the macOS Keychain was completely denying access to Paw, and so far we've been relying on it for the login process. We have worked around this limitation and have found an alternative login mechanism that doesn't entirely relies on the macOS Keychain.

Here's a download link to a beta build for the upcoming bugfix release of Paw: https://cdn-builds.paw.cloud/paw/Paw-3.1.6-3001006002.zip

Login and license activation should be working fine for you with this version. You can log in either from the welcome window or by going to the Paw menu > Preferences > Paw Cloud.

Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Thanks Micha, with that version the problem is gone and I was able to log in and now I can use Paw again. I can confirm that you are right about my MacOS Keychain issues. Looking forward the next stable version.